# tikz left of = node.center

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

Following Problem with tikz:
I want to Position my nodes as seen in the attached Picture.
So "east" of my node "a" is my "west" of node "b"; (in short: a.east=b.west).
in Addition i would love to add a optional space sometimes between a; (a.east=b.west+x).

Additionally i want for other nodes that some nodes to have the same x0,y0-Position.

In the MWE i provided i want the bigger Ellipse's east to match at the rectanlges west. And the smaller Ellipse should have the same x0,y0 as the bigger one.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning}
\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}
 \centering 
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (outer) [rectangle, draw=black, thick, minimum height=4cm,minimum width=3cm]{};
  \node (inin)[ellipse, draw=black, thick, minimum height=2cm, minimum width=0.3cm, right of = outer] {};
  \node (inout)[ellipse, draw=black, thick, minimum height=2.5cm, minimum width=0.5cm, right of =outer] {};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Arch}
\label{fig:Arch}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions?

Edit: i added a second Picture, to make clearer what i want.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that code should be formatted as code (indent by four spaces or highlight and hit the `{}` key) rather than as a quotation. Some line breaks would be good. Perhaps you could edit your question to include them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To place a node `x` distance to the right of node `a`, use:

```
right=x of a
```

`x` might, for example, be `0pt` or `5mm` or whatever.

To place the inner line of the ellipse, it is easiest to draw the outer line first and then place the inner line using `inout.center` to centre the ellipse. This seems simpler, to me, than figuring out the appropriate amount to move to the right.

[image: positioning things]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (outer) [rectangle, draw=black, thick, minimum height=4cm,minimum width=3cm]{};
    \node (inout)[ellipse, draw=black, thick, minimum height=2.5cm, minimum width=0.5cm, right=0pt of outer] {};
    \node (inin)[ellipse, draw=black, thick, minimum height=2cm, minimum width=0.3cm] at (inout.center) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```